# How to find a specific bitcoin address from all the addresses?

Tags: wallet, blockchain, client, address

Recently, I found a site that show all the addresses in a huge list, divided in 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675 pages.

The site's link is http://directory.io/ and I want to know if I can find a certain address from the whole list. I already tried to merge all those pages into one list and then search for the address with the browser, but I'm not sure how to do it (because I don't know much about HTML).

So, if you know a way to do this, please tell me and explain me how. Thanks!

Comment: That's hilarious.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's hilarious *if* it's a malcontent scallywag- perhaps its for noble causes! Op check answer #2

Comment: I wonder how far Google's crawler has gotten into this site.

Comment: @Michael Apparently, [not an insignificant amount of it](http://prntscr.com/4r9a90) (if you assume Google indexes linearly)

Comment: If you know the private key, yes you can. If not, you'll need roughly an eternity to find it.

Comment: directory.io is down, this is up, https://allbitcoinprivatekeys.com/

Answer (score 6):

As [Arturo](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30704/5406) and [Aussie](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30703/5406) already said, [directory.io](http://directory.io) shows all Bitcoin addresses sorted by private key. Also, the author explains his intent on [directory.io/faq](http://directory.io/faq).

The first page has 11.302 Byte. Assuming they all are about the same size, **1TiB would just store 97,284,695 pages.** Yet, there are 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675 pages. That is approximately 9.05 × 10<sup>74</sup>, i.e. ~10<sup>66</sup> TiB.

**There is not enough memory to store them, and it is infeasible to search for one address in them in reasonable time.**

Concluding, everyone's bitcoins are still safe. :)

Answer (score 5):

The site [Directory.io](http://directory.io) is an insider joke; it's simply making the statement that there's 2^256 - 1 (ie X combinations, where X = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336 
) private keys.

A private key can be a large number like 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636601 or small like 0.

So what's been done is each page is essentially a list of hashed numbers in order, starting at n=0, then next n=1, 2, 3, etc *ad nauseum*

Similarly, a hashed number called the secret exponent - a hexadecimal number up to 2^160 in size - represents the public key. You can see the public key for yourself with the *secret exponent* field at [BrainWallet.org](http://brainwallet.org) and the private key proof at the [Directory.io FAQ](http://directory.io/faq).

Comment: It's actually 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336 private keys! http://blog.richardkiss.com/?p=371 ... 1 Mississippi, 2 Mississippi...

Comment: Tiny nit: 0 is not a valid private key. 1 is.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand that site. It 'lists' all possible addresses and you do NOT want to search your own address in there (even if that were possible).

I don't know of the site is a joke or a troll, but best just to avoid it.

Comment: There is not bad faq section there http://directory.io/faq

Comment: Those a too much private keys! just try it. It will take too long to search. directory.io is not available anymore. But there seems to be a new site: allprivatekeys.com. I don't know if its serious so DO NOT CHECK YOUR PRIVATE KEYS THERE but you can check your Bitcon Addresses.

Comment: But you also should not post there any bitcoin addresses with your email address. This would be a good combination for an attack ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also important to note is that [Directory.io](http://directory.io) doesn't actually store any private key (because that would be physically imposible, for a reason [similar to this](http://cointext.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/btcbruteforce.jpg)). Rather, you tell it which page you want to see, and then it shows you the private keys [n*128, (n+1)*128-1], which it calculates on the fly. Your private keys are never compromised by this website.

Comment: UNLESS of course you search for your private key or public key in the list. A malicious webmaster could actually exploit that now I think of it.

Comment: Actually, the theoretical minimum energy to perform any *reversible* computing operation is zero. Yapping about thermodynamics doesn't change that. Sources: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/revcomp/faq.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing

Comment: The link I provided about counting and thermodynamics was an example. The actual storing of such numbers is a different problem that depends on the smallest physical storage posible for a bit. If we take this to be an atom, then we're on a similar scale. We would need almost all atoms in the observable universe to store all of them.

Comment: Also, I would like to know about a real-life computer that actually uses 0 energy (how would it work, anyway?)

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie lol dont ever do that ,  u will give the site's owner shortcut right to your wallet